# Why do ideal Op-Amps have zero offset voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier, offset

Why does ideal operational amplifiers have zero offset voltage? Is that because it has infinite gain?

Comment: This is an engineering question, but it's really just a definition what you call an "ideal OP". You can require infinite gain, infinite bandwidth, zero offset, zero noise, perfect linearity etc.. if you want, or you relax any one of these requirements but keep a combination of the others. In practice it makes little sense to calculate/simulate any circuit with an ideal OP, reality will catch you as soon as you build the circuit, so you better understand how it will perform with a real OP already at the conceptual level.

Comment: because, if you defined an ideal opamp as one having infinite gain then if it also had a nonzero offset then its open loop response would have infinite output voltage.

Comment: *"Why does ideal operational amplifiers have zero offset voltage?"* Because that's part of the definition of "ideal opamp".

Answer (score 1):

Offset is non-ideal behavior. For this reason an ideal opamp does not have offset by definition.

However, this is not a requirement, even with infinite gain offset can be included because opamps are usually used in a feedback configuration that reduces the gain of the closed-loop system.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does ideal operational amplifiers have zero offset voltage?

An op-amp output is given by the formula \$ V_{OUT} = G_{OL}(V_+ - V_-) \$. i.e., the output is the open-loop gain times the difference in voltage between the two inputs. If \$V_+\$ is slightly higher than \$V_-\$ then the output will tend to swing the the positive supply rail and vice versa.

In practice there may be a little offset between the two inputs. The effect of this is to move the transition where the output changes polarity by a few mV. e.g., with an offset voltage of 1 mV the \$V_+\$ input would have to exceed the \$ V_-\$ input by 1 mV before the output would start to go positive.

In many circuits the offset voltage is not too important. In situations where there is high gain it can cause problems as the offset voltage creates an error on the output which is \$ G V_{offset} \$, where G is the closed loop gain. This can cause errors in the accuracy of the circuit (e.g., a measurement circuit) or can cause the op-amp to hit one of the supply rails and cause output clipping.

An ideal op-amp will have zero offset voltage.

> Is that because it has infinite gain?

No. It's not directly related to gain.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what an opamp is supposed to do. It can be used as a comparator, in which case an offset introduces errors. It can also be used in a negative feedback configuration. In this case the offset also introduces deviations from what we would like the opamp to do.

Consider the follower configuration:
[image: follower]
The feedback makes sure the positive terminal is equal to the negative terminal. You put 1V in and you get 1V out. Now assume that you have a 0.1V offset between the terminals. The input is still 1V but the output will be 1.1V.

You see that in the configurations we'd like to use the opamp, we wish that the offset is zero. That is why we define the ideal opamp as having no offset. That is the ideal we are trying to achieve.